# What is the word for "dividing into two unequal parts"?

Tags: word-request

**Halving** is the action of dividing something to two halves, i.e., they are assumed to be of equal sizes.

What is the word for the action of dividing something into two parts, that are not necessarily identical?

Comment: You can always use _break_; if that word has too much ambiguity for your liking, you can say _break in two_. However, it's worth pointing out that the best word may be context-dependent. That is, I wouldn't necessarily use the same word to describe the way I would "divide" a pizza as I would to describe the way a bone broke. I might say the bone _snapped in two_, but I _pruned_ the branch, or I _sliced_ a piece of pizza, or I _bit_ the candy bar (which divides it into two parts: the part in your mouth, and the part left in your hand).

Comment: @J.R. I would say "halving" is less known than using "breaking/dividing into equal parts".

Comment: I think all native speakers know the word *halving*, but in many contexts it's simply not the right word.

Comment: @J.R.'s right on the money, I think. Erel, if you give us the context in which you're trying to use this, we should be able to give you a word appropriate for that context. If you want an all-encompassing term, I don't think there's a common one; we use different words for different actions.

Comment: @snailboat: I agree. Actually, offhand, I can't think of very many contexts where I *would* understand *halve* to mean "to divide into two halves"; it much more often means "to decrease by half".

Comment: I wonder too if 'halving' is pretty infrequent. Can't think of the last time I heard it, certainly haven't said it in decades, and read it here for the first time in years. (OK, sure, maybe I don't get out often enough and halve my time between work and play :-P )

Answer (score 4):

One (somewhat archaic) option is

*Cleave* -- "to split or divide by or as if by a cutting blow, especially along a natural line of division, as the grain of wood." ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cleave?s=t))

This doesn't explicitly create exactly two parts, but generally if you split something with a single blow, you'll only end up with two parts.

An common phrase that does explicitly specify the number of resulting parts is to *split (something) in two*

Answer (score 1):

A lot of words are there. You yourself said [Dividing.](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/divide?q=divide)

> consumer magazines can be **divided** into a number of categories.

There are also [Separate](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/separate?q=separate), [Split](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/split?q=split) etc.

> **Separate** the cake into two parts.
>
> The river had **split** into two channels later in it's way.

None of these mean breaking into into equal parts.

Comment: Yes, but none of them mean breaking into two parts... I want to emphasize that there are two parts, but they are not necessarily equal.

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi , IMO you can divide something in any no of parts,.... 2 is just a number. You can divide something into 2 parts too. But it seems, you want the action to be specific to cutting into 2parts only (_emphasizing 2_); I would say then you are looking for something _verbose_.

Comment: you have to qualify it with "in two parts" as there is no such specific English word (to my knowledge) other than halve. So you cut, cleave, divide, separate, split, chop, saw, tear into, or rip into two parts.  Surely there are other fractionalizing words too :))

Comment: @HowardPautz, I understood the OP's point. That's why I told he is looking for something _superfluous_, _wordy_, _verbose_, _tedious_.

Comment: @Mistu4u there are many English words that are specific to the number 2, for example "couple" (a group of 2), "half" (one of 2 equal parts), "both", etc. So, I thought there may be a word specific for dividing to two parts.

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi , Well, point noted! :-) But sadly, I (_apparently other too_) could not find one.

Answer (score 0):

To use an example that was used by Rowan Atkinson to great comedic effect in one of his religious ministers sketches, I would suggest 'cleft in twain.'
It was an appropriation of Victorian-era Biblical English -meaning it likely dates from the 1700s or even earlier when the Bible was first printed/published.
Seriously now, in most informal English we would say 'split' or 'divided'.

Answer (score 0):

Bisect?

This is supposed to *usually* mean two equal parts, but not always.     From [www.dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com):

```
bisect
verb (used with object)
    to cut or divide into two equal or nearly equal parts.
Origin of bisect 1640–50;
    bi + -sect<Latin sectus, past participle of secāre to cut, sever; see section
```

Comment: Are you asking or answering? Your answer would be improved with something to support bisect being used in the sense the question asks for  .

Answer (score -1):

Bifurcate, splitting in two pieces.

Comment: Bifurcation refers mostly to *forking* or *splitting a passageway*; it's less relevant for chopping something up.

Comment: The definition that I'm familiar with is to divide or split into two branches or channels that are still connected, not to split into two pieces. For example some reptiles have bifurcated , or forked, tongues. I don't think this fits the question.